# Бэкенд на Django REST, фронтенд на Django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-admin, django-orm, django-model

Вообщем, я создал простое приложение на Django. Всё окей, всё работает, но недавно я познакомился с Django REST Framework и теперь у меня есть задача сделать API при помощи Django REST и выводить эти данные в Django в шаблоны. Т.е. изначально мой проект на Django напрямую обращался к БД и брал оттуда данные и дальше выводил их в шаблоны, а я хочу сделать так, чтобы мои данные сначала проходили сериализацию и передавались в шаблоны. Получается, что надо сделать так, чтобы Django REST был в роли бэкенда, а Django в роле фронтенда. Подскажите, реально ли это? Или я спрашиваю какой-то бред?

Comment: Ну от части да, это бред. Преимущество от использования rest достигаются в SPA приложении, а оно мыслить себя не может без js. Даже если первоначальную страницу выдаёт Django

Comment: И что тогда предложите сделать?

Comment: Делать фронт на каком-нибудь vue, react, angular и им подобным